# JTextField is not outputting all of the desired outputs

Tags: java, arrays, swing, user-interface, jtextfield

I am new in Java and currently studying and trying out GUI. I have this problem that converts multiple integer into separated with comma. example is: 12333 = 1,2,3,3,3. It works in `System.out.print` but it doesn't work in `setText` in `JTextField`. I tried many various types on how to convert but it doesn't seem to work when it comes to `JTextField` and `setText`

```java
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("CONVERT");
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int ans, input = 0;
        try {
            input = Integer.parseInt(Input.getText());
        }catch(Exception e1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter a valid Number or Integer");
        }
        String toString = String.valueOf(input);
        char[] toArray = toString.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < toArray.length; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                String s = (Character.toString(toArray[i]));
                /*String output = Character.toString(toArray[i]);*/
                Converted.setText(Character.toString(toArray[i]));
            } else {
                String s = (", " + toArray[i]);
                /*String output = Character.toString(toArray[i]);*/
                Converted.setText(", " + toArray[i]);
            }
        }
    }
});
btnNewButton.setBounds(174, 119, 89, 23);
contentPane.add(btnNewButton);
Converted = new JTextField();
Converted.setColumns(10);
Converted.setBounds(34, 153, 143, 20);
contentPane.add(Converted);
```

This outputs only the last 2 digits. ex is 12345 = ,5

Comment: Take some time to read the JavaDocs for [JTextField#setText](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setText(java.lang.String))

Comment: Thank you for that. I found the answer shortly after my question, trying out the other Components. I used JTextArea and append instead to fix my problem. Sorry for not researching enough and studying swing. I'm not entirely sure though on how to mark this question as answered, Maybe i leave it to mods. Thanks!.

Comment: Thank you for that kleopatra. I will study further especially my naming conventions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try appending and not setting.  You are setting the value in the else statement.  That's why you are getting the last value only.